# How to exclude a typescript file from ionc 2 build/minify using ionic-app-scripts at run time

Tags: ionic2

I created new app using ionic 2 CLI and now ionic has started using **"ionic-app-scripts"** for build and minification.

Earlier ionic used gulp and I excluded typescript files from build process based on few input parameters from command.

how to do it in  ionic-app-scripts ?

I know we have **"tsconfig.json"** where we can define include and exclude but I want to do at run time and based on parameter value like -

ionic serve --istrue

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration

Comment: I have looked into and I do not see any help there!

Comment: not sure what you mean by exclude ts file..?

Comment: Say, I have two file with .ts extension and I don't want to build/minify one file.